# How to keep a number format after I've converted multiple strings to a hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a hyperlink to a cell yet format it "0000". The code I have come up with so far is as the below.

```
Dim PictureNum As String
Dim FolderLoc As String

PictureNum = Format(inputwks.Range("picturenumcell").Value, "0000")
FolderLoc = inputwks.Range("imagefolderpath").Value

with recordwks
.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=.Cells(nextRow, PictureCol2), Address:=(FolderLoc & "\" & PictureNum & ".png"), TextToDisplay:=Format(PictureNum, "0000")
End with
```

The .Cells(nextRow, PictureCol2) in the hyperlinks line puts the picture number as a hyperlink into a specific cell in the recordwks worksheet.

For example, if it's picture number 0002.png, the resulting hyperlink text to display ends up just putting it as "2" rather than "0002"

How do I modify it to make it say "0002"?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try setting the number format on the cell?  You can record a macro while doing that - it should give you what you need.

Comment: You could either have it insert a string or specify `cells().numberformat = "0000"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefixing cell content with `'` will make Excel treat it as text, so you can do this:

```
TextToDisplay:= "'" & Format(PictureNum, "0000")
```